# What is this padding above the text label and how do I handle it?

Tags: html, css

I added a label to my page and there is padding above the label so it's not in the location I've designed it to be. I want to remove all the space above the text so it is flush to the location I've set it at. The larger the font size the farther from the location I've set it to be.

What the heck is going on here?

Here's the code of one of the labels:

```
<label id="Label1551">12pt</label>

#Label2125  {
    position:absolute;
    left:309px;
    top:5px;
    width:150px;
    height:61px;
    color:#000000;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:64px;
}
```

I've added an outline around the labels so you can see the result.

[image]

**UPDATE**:
Here is more updated code here, http://jsfiddle.net/6gLQU/8/. I'm still seeing a gap at the top albeit a smaller gap. Here is the updated screen shot. Is it possible there is another issue besides the line-height?

[image]

**Update 2024**
Related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34983672/is-there-a-way-to-make-text-characters-flush-to-the-top-of-their-bounding-box-in).

Answer (score 3):

That is not padding, it is `line-height`. I see that you haven't specified a line-height in your css, but it will inherit `line-height` from the stylesheet. So try giving a `line-height` same as that of the `font-size`

Comment: I've updated the CSS to include line-height but as the font size grows there is a gap that is added. I've included an updated screenshot and linked to the updated code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can remove unwanted top/bottom font space using the following method. This is different than the padding style.

#### Check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6gLQU/)

[image]

You can manage using following two properties,

```
height:50px;    
line-height:50px;
```

Let me explain, if you want to remove top space, set `height` as well as the `line-height` property (see jsFiddle demo).

The font-size is set to 64px but the actually size is around `50px`. So to remove this extra `14px` space set the height as well as the line-height property to remove the unwanted space.

Comment: This has helped remove a majority of the top space. I've updated my example but there is still a little space left. Do you know if it there is any other property affecting the top space?

Comment: @1.21gigawatts Form one of [my answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22193521/1725764): `That space belongs to the characters themselves; Which means you have to edit the font via a Font editor application to align the characters vertically in their code point.`