# CSS Crossbrowser issue : Substitute for Grid template columns value

Tags: css, cross-browser

Hello I'm using this css style :

```
grid-template-columns : repeat(auto-fill,minmax(250px,1fr));
grid-auto-rows: 350px;
```

But it's not working on other browsers like IE. I tried to use css crossbrowser code generator, but I can't find the substitute for this. What I want to do is to display products in a card form, 3 per row, with a specific row size. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `caniuse.com` says IE has partial support for css grid and flex with the `-ms-` prefix. If it's just not working and you have to use IE, try using floats for your layout.

Comment: is it possible to only apply float (or other compatible style) when the browser is IE?

Comment: I don't really know the answer to that question, but [here is a thread on it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32547370/is-there-a-way-to-set-any-style-for-a-specific-browser-in-css) It's not wrong or bad to use floats, and could serve your needs well. In fact [here's a really helpful codepen with a three box/card per row layout.](https://codepen.io/brianjensen/pen/qgyQQm)